# Porting Windows software

Tags: opencv, windows, qtonpi

I would like to know is it possible to port software that uses OpenCV, OpenGL and QT on Windows to the Raspberry Pi.

I wonder is it a must to use Qtonpi dist? 
I need resources like books, tutorials to support me for doing that task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be done, in theory, as all of these libraries can be built for ARMv6 (as far as I'm aware). The key thing to note is that **the i386 instruction set which Windows uses will not run on the ARMv6 based processor used by the Raspberry Pi**.
This means that the program would not be executable in a form compiled for Windows - **even under Wine**. You would have to get access to the source code of the program and recompile it. Even then there would likely be issues as it's likely that the software uses features of the programming language or of other libraries which won't run on an ARM processor.

TL;DR: Not without access to the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) - it's designed for running windows executables on a GNU/Linux system. I haven't tryed it in Debian (Raspbian on the Pi) or ArchLinux but it has been useful on Ubuntu for running simple windows applications such as Notepad++.

There is lots of documentation on the Wine site and it has been around for ages on various distributions. Let us know how you go!

Comment: Wine doesn't work on the Pi due to it running on an ARM processor, not an i386 based processor. Wine is not a hardware emulator.